# Pulling example data point from linear regression model

Tags: r, linear-regression

I've recently created a linear regression model in R-Studio found below:

```
> model1 = lm(price~sqft_living,train)

> pred_train = predict(model1)
> rmse_train = sqrt(mean((pred_train - train$price)^2))
> rmse_train
[1] 261068.9

> pred_test = predict(model1,newdata=test)
> rmse_test = sqrt(mean((pred_test - test$price)^2))
> rmse_test
[1] 262334.4

> sse = sum((pred_train - train$price)^2)
> sst = sum((mean(train$price)-train$price)^2)
> r2 = 1 - sse/sst
> r2
[1] 0.4967993

> summary(model1)

Call:
lm(formula = price ~ sqft_living, data = train)

Residuals:
     Min       1Q   Median       3Q      Max 
-1491759  -146386   -24131   106578  4348558 

Coefficients:
              Estimate Std. Error t value            Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept) -47764.278   5250.938  -9.096 <0.0000000000000002 ***
sqft_living    282.092      2.305 122.381 <0.0000000000000002 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Residual standard error: 261100 on 15170 degrees of freedom
Multiple R-squared:  0.4968,    Adjusted R-squared:  0.4968 
F-statistic: 1.498e+04 on 1 and 15170 DF,  p-value: < 0.00000000000000022
```

My issue is that I need to see "based on `model1`, on average, what would a 1400 square foot house cost?"

Although it sounds kind of silly, I have no idea how to actually find this in my model and I've had no luck searching it online. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Below is some code showing what the dataset looks like:

```
> dput(head(houses))
structure(list(id = c(7129300520, 6414100192, 5631500400, 2487200875, 
1954400510, 7237550310), price = c(221900, 538000, 180000, 604000, 
510000, 1225000), bedrooms = c(3, 3, 2, 4, 3, 4), bathrooms = c(1, 
2.25, 1, 3, 2, 4.5), sqft_living = c(1180, 2570, 770, 1960, 1680, 
5420), sqft_lot = c(5650, 7242, 10000, 5000, 8080, 101930), floors = c(1, 
2, 1, 1, 1, 1), waterfront = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), view = c(0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0), condition = c(3, 3, 3, 5, 3, 3), grade = c(7, 
7, 6, 7, 8, 11), sqft_above = c(1180, 2170, 770, 1050, 1680, 
3890), sqft_basement = c(0, 400, 0, 910, 0, 1530), yr_built = c(1955, 
1951, 1933, 1965, 1987, 2001), yr_renovated = c(0, 1991, 0, 0, 
0, 0), age = c(59, 63, 82, 49, 28, 13)), row.names = c(NA, -6L
), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))

> glimpse(houses)
Rows: 21,613
Columns: 16
$ id            <dbl> 7129300520, 6414100192, 5631500400, 2487200875, 195440051…
$ price         <dbl> 221900, 538000, 180000, 604000, 510000, 1225000, 257500, …
$ bedrooms      <dbl> 3, 3, 2, 4, 3, 4, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 2, 3, 3, 5, 4, 3, 4, 2, …
$ bathrooms     <dbl> 1.00, 2.25, 1.00, 3.00, 2.00, 4.50, 2.25, 1.50, 1.00, 2.5…
$ sqft_living   <dbl> 1180, 2570, 770, 1960, 1680, 5420, 1715, 1060, 1780, 1890…
$ sqft_lot      <dbl> 5650, 7242, 10000, 5000, 8080, 101930, 6819, 9711, 7470, …
$ floors        <dbl> 1.0, 2.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 2.0, 1.0, 1.0, 2.0, 1.0, 1.…
$ waterfront    <dbl> 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, …
$ view          <dbl> 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3, 0, 0, 0, …
$ condition     <dbl> 3, 3, 3, 5, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, …
$ grade         <dbl> 7, 7, 6, 7, 8, 11, 7, 7, 7, 7, 8, 7, 7, 7, 7, 9, 7, 7, 7,…
$ sqft_above    <dbl> 1180, 2170, 770, 1050, 1680, 3890, 1715, 1060, 1050, 1890…
$ sqft_basement <dbl> 0, 400, 0, 910, 0, 1530, 0, 0, 730, 0, 1700, 300, 0, 0, 0…
$ yr_built      <dbl> 1955, 1951, 1933, 1965, 1987, 2001, 1995, 1963, 1960, 200…
$ yr_renovated  <dbl> 0, 1991, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, …
$ age           <dbl> 59, 63, 82, 49, 28, 13, 19, 52, 55, 12, 50, 72, 87, 37, 1…
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To predict the value of the response given new values for the regressors, just create a new data set and use it in `predict`, objects output by R's modelling functions are S3 class objects therefore the odds are that there are methods, in this case `predict`, written for them.

```
model <- lm(price ~ sqft_living, houses)

new <- data.frame(sqft_living = 1400)
predict(model, newdata = new)
#       1 
#357469.5
```

---

As for the RMSE in the question, the following is simpler.

```
rmse <- function(object){
  e <- resid(object)
  sqrt(mean(e^2, na.rm = TRUE))
}

rmse(model)
#[1] 80374.95
```

---

As for the follow-up question in comment,

> Based on model1, if a homeowner were to put in a 200 square foot addition on the house, how much would the price be expected to go up by?

the answer is simple, the model's coefficient of the `sqft_living` term is the expected variation in `price` that an increase in 1 unit of the regressor will on average cause.

```
coef(model)
#(Intercept) sqft_living 
# 50960.6653    218.9349 
 
coef(model)[2] * 200
#sqft_living 
#   43786.98
```

This result can also be obtained if the prices for 2 values of `sqft_living` 200 units apart are computed.

```
new2 <- data.frame(sqft_living = c(1400, 1400 + 200))
ypred <- predict(model, newdata = new2)

diff(ypred)
#       2 
#43786.98
```

The same value as above.

Comment: Incredible - thank you so much. I have a follow-up to this question though: "Based on model1, if a homeowner were to put in a 200 square foot addition on the house, how much would the price be expected to go up by?"
Is this even answerable since it would vary based on the original ```sqrf_living``` right?